# How to fix this function?

Tags: r, statistics

I am doing an exercise to create a function. One of the questions is:

"We can estimate the cumulative risk of an certain event using the 
exponential formula
`1-exp(-1/10000*t)` where t is the time to the event. Create a function ans(t), which returns the risk at time t.

and I am using this command:

```
function(t){ans(t)<-1-exp(-1/10000*t)return(ans(t))}
```

but it is giving wrong answer. Can someone help me to understand this please?

Comment: The syntax for defining a function in R is `myfun <- function(...) {...}` where the first ... is the arguments and the second ... is the body of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper format to define a function is this:

```
ans<-function(t){
   answer<-1-exp(-1/10000*t)
   return(answer)
}

ans(1)
#[1] 9.9995e-05
```